# Getting an error while running ansible playbook for changing EC2 volume type from GP2 to GP3

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, automation, ansible, redhat

I'm using `amazon.aws 1.2.0`, and keep getting this error message:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.aws.ec2_vol'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
```

The error appears to be in `/ansible/change_ec2_volume.yml` on the line line 16, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem. Tried changing this line but the error still occurs.

ansible/change_ec2_volume.yml:

```
    - name: Change EBS volume type to GP3
      ^ here
```

My code:

```
- name: Change EBS Volume Type from GP2 to GP3
  hosts: slave
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
    - vars_volume.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Get all GP2 EBS volumes
      community.aws.ec2_instance_info:
        filters:
          instance-state-name: running
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
      register: ec2_instances

    - name: Change EBS volume type to GP3
      community.aws.ec2_vol:
        instance: "{{ item.instance_id }}"
        state: present
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        volume_type: gp3
      loop: "{{ ec2_instances.instances }}"
```

Comment: My answer was deleted even after I edited it to meet the stackoverflow elitists' requirements, so I don't know if it was flat out wrong or still not up to par, but I don't want to leave you hanging. It was essentially that there is no ec2_vol module in the community.aws collection, however there is one in the amazon.aws collection.